# Unable to construct a Multimap with a given Datatype

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have my own class "3DSolid" and I am trying to insert items into a Multimap
So,I am defining my Multimap like this:

```
std::multimap< 3DSolid, 3DSolid > &SolidsolidMapping;
```

and I am inserting the items like this:

```
    SolidsolidMapping.insert( std::make_pair( solid1, solid2 ) );
```

where solid1 and solid2 are objects of my class 3DSolid.

So, now I get an error regarding the "bool < operator"  saying: binary <: no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type const '3DSolid'...".

So,I defined the operator like this:

```
bool operator<( const 3DSolid& _Left, const 3DSolid& _Right )
{
    return _Left < _Right;
}
```

Then,I don't get any compilation errors. But when I run my program, it crashes, as the operator,which I have defined does not make any sense.I just want to construct an unsorted Multimap. I am not concerned regarding the "operator <".

I would be really glad, if someone can suggest my changes in the code
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I just want to construct an unsorted Multimap. I am not concerned regarding the "operator <".*  Well you have to be concerned about that, `multimap` does need an ordering between elements inserted.

Comment: @Gaurav Sehgal: I tried using the data structure, std::unsorted_multimap, but I still get an error , since the class Object,which I am using is not a typical C++ Class Object

Comment: If you cannot define an ordering between different `3DSolid` , you cannot use any container that needs ordering(`map`, `multimap` et al).

Comment: What do you mean by "not a typical C++ Class Object"?

Answer (score 0):

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimaphttp://) (highlighting mine):

> Multimap is an associative container that contains a **sorted** list of
>   key-value pairs, while permitting multiple entries with the same key.

If you cannot sort your items, a `multimap` is not what you want. Try an explicitely unordered structure if there is not meaningful comparison function for your items, such as an [unordered multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap). The reason for this distinction is that operations like random access are much more efficient on sorted datasets.

Comment: I should be able to use "unsorted_multimap" right??

Answer (score 0):

Others already explained why you should **not** use `multimap`, but `unsorted_multimap` instead.

> Then,I don't get any compilation errors. But when I run my program, it
>   crashes.

The problem why program crashes is, that your overloaded operator **recursively call it self** and it causes *stack overflow* due to recursive calls. See [here](https://ideone.com/PSaP5O).

```
bool operator<( const 3DSolid& _Left, const 3DSolid& _Right )
{
    return _Left < _Right;
}
```

Correct operator overloaded method should use its members (See [here](https://ideone.com/z7tVqv)), like so:

```
bool operator<( const 3DSolid& _Left, const 3DSolid& _Right )
{
    return _Left.getBar() < _Right.getBar();
}
```